# Axis naming for multiple parameters in one graph

Tags: writing, graphics

I have four angles and I like to show them in a angle–time graph using Matlab’s plot function. The problem is the naming of vertical y-axis. Should it be:

- plural, i.e., *Position Angles* since the graph is showing four different angles, or
- singular, i.e., *Position Angle* as shown below since the important point is the meaningful explanation of axes regardless of parameter count given in the graph?

[image: The plot mentioned in the question with singular y-axis naming]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about charting conventions, not academia

Comment: I am writing a master thesis so I like to take opinion of people here rather than those at english.se. I think this is a nice point and should stay for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the singular, "Position Angle," because an axis is  interpreted as referring to *each data element individually*.

In order words, at time 0.4, the red line is not at approximately "60 angles," but is at an angle of approximately 60 degrees.